# Stripping leading and trailing non digit characters in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Coming from perl, I'm trying to do this:

```
$dollar1 = 'USD -$1,009.00 USD' ;
$dollar1 =~ s/^\D+// ; 
$dollar1 =~ s/\D+$// ;
```

in python. I've tried the following and a couple of other iterations. Googling I'm seeing a lot of examples of global match and replace, but not with anchors, and some examples using type specific methods. But I'm still not getting the desired output, of just "d,d.d"

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

```
import re

dollar1 = 'USD -$1,009.00 USD' # example format

re_leadgarbage = re.compile(r'^\D+')
re_trailgarbage = re.compile(r'\D+$') 

dollar1 = re_leadgarbage.sub(dollar1, "")
dollar1 = re_trailgarbage.sub(dollar1, "")

print (dollar1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of arguments in the regex object’s `sub` method is `replacement, string`:

```
dollar1 = re_leadgarbage.sub("", dollar1)
dollar1 = re_trailgarbage.sub("", dollar1)
```

Consider also using `\Z` (end of string) instead of `$` (optional newline, end of string) and note that you can make only one replacement with `^\D+|\D+\z`. Also, `\d` matches all Unicode digits, so consider `[^0-9]` instead of `\D` if you don’t want to get ٣.

Comment: Compilation isn't necessary for performance if there are only a few regular expressions in your script, but it's a stronger form of reuse than simply setting `re_leadgarbage = r'^\D+'` and passing that value around to multiple calls to `re.sub`.

Comment: @chepner: There’s no reuse here, though.

Comment: It's a test example; my point is there's little to gain by telling the OP *not* to compile.

Comment: @chepner: If they don’t realize you don’t need to compile, “you don’t need to compile” is helpful. Compare the Perl. It’s a common misconception.

Comment: assume that there is reuse neccessary.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard of anyone who thought that compiling was *necessary*. If anything, it's a misconception that precompiling will always lead to a performance improvement, as many people fail to realize that `re` automatically caches a good number of regular expressions. Using `re.compile` can be a good practice for self-documenting code even if it doesn't lead to a performance increase. So again, why is 50% of the answer devoted to a meaningless change to the OP's code?

Comment: @chepner: I have ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Mostly people used to .NET. Anyway, I brought it up, again, because the original Perl has the regexes inline. It’s only 50% of the answer by height; by content, it’s 7 words.

Comment: @JamesAanderson: The answer is the same regardless of reuse. You have the argument order wrong. See the entire rest of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, try:

```
import re
dollar1 = 'USD -$1,009.00 USD'
print re.search('([0-9,.])+', dollar1).group()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your input data like what you have mentioned e.g `'USD -$1,009.00 USD'`, `'USD $1,95858.98 USD'` etc. then you can also get it using the below approach.

```
>>> dollar1 = 'USD -$1,009.00 USD'
>>> money = dollar1.split('$')[1].split()[0]
>>>
>>> money
'1,009.00'
```